# Arranging identical blue and red bottles such that there are no 2 red bottles next to each other

Tags: combinatorics

There are 10 identical blue bottles and 5 identical red bottles. How many ways are
there to arrange the 15 bottles in a row such that no two red bottles are next to
each other?

My approach:

If the 2 red bottles are not to be next to each other, then there are 11 places for the red bottles. So my answer is $\binom{11}{5}$ but I'm not sure whether it's correct.

Comment: The answer is right, and the description of the reason is good, perhaps a little brief. Place the $10$ blues in a row, with a little gap between them. There are then $11$ gaps, including the $2$ endgaps. We need to choose $5$ of them to slip a red into.